# wlst startServer show credential in plain text

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, wlst

I'm running my AdminServer off-line via startServer() command. The server seems to start just fine, but when i check the proccess shows the credentials in plain text. Like this calling jps -v:

---

```
24575 Server -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dweblogic.management password=secretpass<<<<---not good
```

---

I'm running the command this way.:

---

```
startServer('AdminServer','Domain','t3://url:6101','user','secretpass','/u01/home/app/welogicuser/domains/Domain','true',60000,'false', jvmArgs='-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dweblogic.security.SSL.trustedCAKeyStore='+os.environ["WL_HOME"]+'/server/lib/cacerts -Xverify:none -da -Dplatform.home='+os.environ["WL_HOME"]+' -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile='+os.environ["WL_HOME"]+'/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties -Djava.security.policy='+os.environ["WL_HOME"]+'/server/lib/weblogic.policy')
```

---

and without the user and pass

---

```
startServer('AdminServer','Domain','t3://url:6101',domainDir='/u01/home/app/user/domains/Domain', block='true',timeout=60000, serverLog='false', jvmArgs='-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile='+os.environ["DOMAIN_HOME"]+'/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties')
```

---

The only way i can run the AdminServer without showing the credentials is running the script ./startWebLogic.sh, but in my currently situation it is not very practical. ¿Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a boot.properties file in your admin server security directory, and specify the user name and password in there as:

```
username=<username>
password=<password>
```

This is described in more detail at https://getsomeoracle.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/how-to-configure-weblogic-username-password-in-boot-properties/

Comment: I already tryed that, look at the jvmArgs. '-Dweblogic.system.BootIdentityFile='+os.environ["WL_HOME"]+'/servers/AdminServer/security/boot.properties' with and without the user and pass elements. But the same result.

Comment: it seems to be a "problem" with WLST, anyway it is always better to use the mentioned start-up script or use node manager directly

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the boot.properties file should be the way to go. It may be that it is still showing the username/password in plain text because you're in development mode. Try turning on production mode, this should encrypt the username and password in the boot.properties file after the first server startup. Since these are the credentials being used on startup, it should solve your problem.